# Physical interpretation of different thermodynamic potentials?

Tags: thermodynamics

I've spent a long time not really understanding what the different thermodynamic potentials physically represent. I see on Wikipedia that for instance the internal energy is defined as the "capacity to do work plus the capacity to release heat" whereas the Gibbs energy is the "capacity to do non-mechanical work".

When we say the "capacity to do work" what does that actually mean? Does this mean if I contain a (possibly ideal?) gas in a diathermal container with a piston and cool it to absolute zero the total amount of energy I have extracted is "internal energy"? If so, if I repeat this procedure with an adiabatic container and a piston and cool it again to 0K with the piston the amount of energy I've extracted is the Helmholtz free energy? But since I'm just extracting all of the energy from the system surely I will have removed the exact same amount?

My misunderstanding is probably pretty fundamental, what I really want is a physical interpretation of what these mean. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check out this link: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/thepot.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, when they mention the energy to "create" a system what does that mean?


"The internal energy U might be thought of as the energy required to create a system in the absence of changes in temperature or volume."

Comment: In thermodynamics a "system" need to be defined, or you might say, created. Everything else is the surroundings. Which means the system needs to have energy and mass attributed to it.  I don't recall the link saying "in the absence of changes in temperature or volume", but changes in temperature or volume are generally associated with changes in internal energy due to work and or heat transfers between the system and surroundings, as opposed to the internal energy itself.